# Group by the Class of Object in JPQL

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, jpql

The JavaEE app with JPA and JSF is having a Bill Entity which is sub classed to BilledBill, CancelledBill and RefundBill.
I use EclipseLink as persistance provider.
I want to write a query which groups the sum of totals by the type of the class.
I tired, but failed.
Is that possible?

The relevant constructor is as below.

```
public BillSummery(PaymentMethod paymentMethod, Class billClass, Double total, Double discount, Double netTotal, Double tax, Long count, BillType billType) {
    this.paymentMethod = paymentMethod;
    this.total = total;
    this.discount = discount;
    this.netTotal = netTotal;
    this.tax = tax;
    this.count = count;
    this.billType = billType;
    this.BillClass = billClass;
}
```

The JPQL is as below

```
String j = "select new com.divudi.data.BillSummery(b.paymentMethod, type(b), sum(b.total), sum(b.discount), sum(b.netTotal), sum(b.vat), count(b), b.billType) "
            + " from Bill b "
            + " where b.retired=false "
            + " and b.billTime between :fd and :td "
            + " group by b.paymentMethod, type(b), b.billType";
```

Comment: What do you mean you failed - did you get an error or what is going wrong?  Simplify your query to just sum the totals and group by type(b) and work up from there.  "Select sum(b.total), type(b) as bill_type from Bill b group by bill_type".  Once you've built up your JPQL query, then look at the return types and make sure they fit your constructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which inheritance strategy are you using?

If it involves a discriminator column, you can always map it as a regular column, just like any other property. It will then be available for use in queries.

Example:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "dtype")
public abstract class Bill {

    @Column(name = "dtype", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private String type;
    ...
}
```

That being said, I'd seriously consider flattening the inheritance structure. It sounds as though a `Bill` could turn into a `BilledBill` or `CancelledBill`, so perhaps it would be sufficient for `Bill` to have a `status` property instead?

Comment: I have modified the inheritance the way you suggested. Now there is no need to group by the type. Thank you